# Rmarkdown knitting YAML LaTeX error

Tags: r, yaml, r-markdown, pandoc

I'm trying to have a script knit an Rmd file to a PDF document and faced some errors.

I must say, document knits fine if I click on the knit button in Rstudio but it fails to knit if I use the command:

```
rmarkdown::render('diagnostic.Rmd',output_format = "pdf_document",
                  output_file = "diag.pdf")
```

The first error I get comes from this part of my code:

```
---
author: Zigo_datateam
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
geometry: margin=1.6in
header-includes: "\\usepackage{fancyhdr} \\fancyfoot[CO,CE]{My footer}"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    toc: false
title: "Graphic Layout(Report)"

---
```

and is:

```
   Error in yaml::yaml.load(string, ...) : 
  Scanner error: while scanning a simple key at line 4, column 1could 
  not find expected ':' at line 5, column 1
```

So, if I remove the hole `header-includes`expression it seems to start knitting but then I get a second error from this part (which comes after the second "---"):

```
\addtolength{\headheight}{1.0cm}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\rhead{\includegraphics[height=1.2cm]{logo.png}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
```

ERROR:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \undefinedpagestyle 

l.130 ...headheight}{1.0cm} \pagestyle{fancyplain}
```

How can I get rid of the first error without getting the second one?

**Update:** I decided to move all footer/header styles to a separate file and my code looks like this:

```
---
author: Zigo_datateam
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
geometry: margin=1.6in
output: 
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: mystyles.sty
title: "Graphic Layout(Report)"
---
```

The errors I talked about earlier stoped showing but I still get this:

```
pandoc: Error producing PDF
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
```

Comment: I would include latex packages using the answer from here : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171711/how-to-include-latex-package-in-r-markdown

Comment: Do you still have the `Error in yaml::yaml.load()` after indenting the `toc: false` line?

Comment: Yes, error persists

Answer (score 1):

In your YAML, use

```
header-includes: 
  - \usepackage{fancyhdr} 
  - \fancyfoot[CO,CE]{My footer}
```

And it should work.

Comment: This does work when clicking the knit button in Rstudio but produces the same errors when using `rmarkdown::render()`

Comment: That's odd. I use this style of formatting with `render` daily. Could you try moving you `fancyfoot` to the body of the document?

Comment: Yes, I moved all formatting to a separate "mystyles.sty" file as I explained in the update. Problem was solved by creating a new Rmd file copy/pasting every line at the time. Thank you very much.